# Integration over a bounded set

Tags: integration

Let $S$ be a bounded set; let $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function. Let $A=\operatorname{int} S$, give an example where $\int_Af$ exists and  $\int_Sf$ does not (i'm working with Riemann integrals).

This proves that the converse of the following theorem is not always true:
If $f$ is Riemann-integrable over the bounded set $S$, then is also Riemann-integrable over $\operatorname{int} S$.

Comment: Are you working with Riemann integrals or with Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: Sorry, i'm working with Riemann integrals

Answer (score 3):

Consider $S=(\Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1] ) \cup [2,3]$ and $f(x)=1$. Clearly $f$ is continuous on $S$ since it is constant, and both $f$ and $S$ are bounded.

Now, $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $S$, but it is on $\operatorname{int} S =(2,3)$.

Comment: You're right man, too easy

Comment: $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $A=\text{int} S=(2,3)$? Why?